# How to add a signature in UNIX mail command

Tags: email, unix

How do I add a signature in a mail that is sent through `mail` command of UNIX ?
I tried it by saving text in `.signature` and in `.sig` files but that didn't work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which 'mail' command do you have? bsd-mailx? Heirloom mailx? s-nail? Yes, `.signature` should be the default, but maybe your system has custom configuration?

Comment: I just used `mail` command to send a mail. I do not know which 'mail' command I am using. I am a beginner. Could you please let me know how to check what is that 'mail' command I am using ? @grawity

Answer (score 1):

According to `man mail`, `mailx` will insert content of `${MAILX_TAIL}` at the end of outgoing mail.

Have you tried it ?

```
MAILX_TAIL="J. Smith. \njsmith@example.com\ntel:1234\n"
export MAILX_TAIL
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. @Archemar And the thing is I am accessing the UNIX server remotely. Will that matter ?